# Configuring SELINUX to allow logging to a file that's outside /var/log

Tags: linux, selinux, syslog, rsyslog

I have a daemon that uses syslog(3) to log to a file that is not a descendant of /var/log. Currently, this requires that SELINUX be disabled. How can I configure an enabled SELINUX to allow this logging?

I am an SELINUX novice. Any guidance or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: PSA - https://stopdisablingselinux.com/

Comment: @0xSheepdog: whoever owns that website should update their TLS configuration. My current browsers refuse to open the website.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you look at the context set for the directory /var/log you'll noticed the following things.

First, the directory `/var/log` has the following selinux context set:

```
$ ls -Z /var | grep "log$"
drwxr-xr-x. root root    system_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0   log
```

Second, the log file, `/var/log/messages`, has no additional context:

```
$ ls -Z /var/log/messages
-rw------- root root ?                                /var/log/messages
```

So it would seem that you only need to set a context similar to the one on `/var/log` on whatever directory you're planning on writing this additional log file to. Something like this should do it.

#### Method #1: replicating selinux label

Below will copy the context that's associated with `/var/log` and apply it to `/opt/blah` as well.

```
$ mkdir /opt/blah
$ ls -Z /opt | grep blah
drwxr-xr-x  root root ?                                   blah

# label directory with context
$ chcon --reference /var/log /opt/blah

# see the newly added context
$ ls -Z /opt/ | grep blah
drwxr-xr-x. root root    system_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0   blah
```

#### Method #2: applying context directly

You can also apply them directly like so:

```
$ chcon system_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0 /opt/blah
```

I'm away from a system where I can confirm the need to run these commands but I believe you need to tell SELinux to pick up these newly applied contexts to the filesystem as well.

```
$ semanage fcontext -a -t var_log_t "/opt(/.*)?"
$ restorecon -R -v /opt
```

#### confirm changes

```
# confirm identical to /var/log context
$ ls -Z /var/ | grep "log$"
drwxr-xr-x. root root    system_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0   log
```

#### References

- [RHEL Deployment Guide - Chapter 44. Working With SELinux](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/rhlcommon-chapter-0017.html)
- [CentOS SELinux Howto](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux)
- [⁠5.6.2. Persistent Changes: semanage fcontext](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files-Persistent_Changes_semanage_fcontext.html)

Comment: Where are the actual commands? I only see comments like `# label directory with context`

Comment: @lorenzog - The command are everything that come after a `$`. That's demarkation for a prompt. Everything w/ a `#` is a comment.